# save value of foreach loop in locally intiliazed array in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to save value of foreach loop coming from a query in locally intialized array.As i dont know how to dynamically save values of foreach loop in array.Code is shown below :

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM interestclass where SortingCode='bake1r20210113' || SortingCode='bake1r20210225' || SortingCode='bake1r20210506' || SortingCode='bake1r20210612' || SortingCode='bake1r20210813'" );
$resultCount = count($result);
$arrayofDates[]=array();
foreach ( $result as $key=>$print )  

     {
         if(substr($print->LessonCode,6)=="01")
         {
             $arrayofDates[]=date("m/d", strtotime(str_replace(' ', '', $print->StartDate)));
             echo "<td>(".$arrayofDates." ,</td>";
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save date to $arrayofDates.the code would look like this

```php
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM interestclass where SortingCode='bake1r20210113' || SortingCode='bake1r20210225' || SortingCode='bake1r20210506' || SortingCode='bake1r20210612' || SortingCode='bake1r20210813'" );
$resultCount = count($result);
$arrayofDates = []; // or $arrayofDates = array()
foreach ( $result as $key=>$print ){
         if(substr($print->LessonCode,6)=="01")
         {
             $date = date("m/d", strtotime(str_replace(' ', '', $print->StartDate)));
             $arrayofDates[] = $date
             echo "<td>".$date." ,</td>"; //you should not echo array in each loop and not concat array to str
         }
}
```

Hope this can help you.if you have further question please comment below